# Sample "Hello, World" ScriptedRecordSetWriter with Python in Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I cannot find any examples of writing a bare bones ScriptedRecordSetWriter using Python for nifi.  I'm looking to figure out how to just get it working, grabbing the incoming flow file and sending "Hello World" out the other side.

I am using JsonTreeReader as the Record reader, but I want to generate a fixed width record as the output.  I can do this with Python easily.  However, I have been able to get past the "No RecordSetWriterFactory" defined in the script.  There is simply no documentation that I can find about what steps to take.

I believe with a simple example I can make it work.  Please help!  :)

Comment: could you share your code and the full error message?

Comment: @daggett That's my issue; I have no idea where/how to start.  I tried to just use a script like you can use in the ExecuteScript processor:

flowFile = session.get() 
if (flowFile != None):
  flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'myAttr', 'myValue')

This fails b/c session is not defined.  So, I'm looking for an example of a full ScriptedRecordSetWriter implemention in Python. Thank you!

Comment: Check this for ScriptedRecordSetWriter: https://www.alasdairb.com/posts/getting-started-with-nifis-scriptedreader-by-processing-key-value-pairs-part-1/

Comment: @tonykoval Thank you; I was able to get the basics from your post.  However, I start off with these two lines:

`from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import InputStreamCallback, InputStreamCallback
from org.apache.nifi.processors.standard import RecordReader, RecordReaderFactory`

And when I enable the controller service, I get an error:

ImportError: No module named standard

So, obviously, my imports aren't working.  Do you know what package or .nar file would hold that module?

Comment: The RecordReader and RecordReaderFactory classes are in the `org.apache.nifi.serialization` package. The associated library should be available to ScriptedRecordSetWriter